# Open a modal popup div with new URL (like instagram)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to replicate the Instagram behavior for modal popups. If you go to an IG page (say https://www.instagram.com/thehughjackman/), and click on one of his pics, a modal popup comes up with the picture enlarged, and the URL immediately changes to the specific page URL (like https://www.instagram.com/p/Bwedsp-HEF3/). When you click on the back button, the modal box closes, and the URL resets to the main page URL. How can I replicate this behavior?

I have used the HTML5 history API to set the URL through javascript, but still cannot replicate the back button behavior. Here's some sample code I have (the CSS isn't perfect but more or less this is the idea) -

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function ChangeUrl(title, url) {
    if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
        var obj = { Title: title, Url: url };
        history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
    } else {
        alert("Browser does not support HTML5.");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").click(function() {
        ChangeUrl('', '?q=abcd');
        $("#modal").html(`<img id="big" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/14/20/11/japanese-cherry-trees-324175_960_720.jpg">`).show();
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#modal {
    display: none;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 2px solid #777;
}

#thumb {
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #555;
}

#big {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="test"><img id="thumb" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/14/20/11/japanese-cherry-trees-324175_960_720.jpg"></a>

<div id="modal"></div>
```

Comment: listen on window.onpopstate to handle back button I guess

Comment: @ducmai could you explain further? With a line of code if possible?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to listen on popState to handle back button like the following

```
function ChangeUrl(title, url) {
    if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
        var obj = { Title: title, Url: url };
        history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
    } else {
        alert("Browser does not support HTML5.");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").click(function() {
        ChangeUrl('', '?q=abcd');
        $("#modal").html(`<img id="big" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/14/20/11/japanese-cherry-trees-324175_960_720.jpg">`).show();
    });
    window.onpopstate = function(event) {
      console.log('on popstate');
      $('#modal').html('');
    };

});
```

Comment: The problem is, onpopstate is getting fired when I click on the thumbnail, so `$("#modal").html()` is always getting set to blank.

Comment: Can you share a working sandbox? It seems a little bit strange because you push state when showing modal

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate. According this so pushstate will not fire onpostate

Comment: interesting, I cannot investigate further justnow. but there is another fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vsb23/2/ which works fine with push and pop

Comment: I suspect because you have a with # wrapped the image so it makes the link changes. change it to another tag link span or add e.preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a Bootstrap modal, you can add a function on modal hide event that will revert the URL back to what it was. Something like this:

```
var stored_variable_of_previous_url;

$('#modal').on("hide.bs.modal", function (e) {
   history.replaceState(null, null, stored_variable_of_previous_url);
});
```

The `replaceState` method above switches out the URL in the address bar with no assets being requested and the window remaining on the same page. This is because replaceState does not manipulate the browser's history, it simply replaces the current URL in the address bar.

You would then add something like this to your function that creates/opens the modal:

```
stored_variable_of_previous_url = window.location.href;
```

Comment: Thank you, this'll work. However, how do I handle the event of the user hitting the back button on the browser?

Comment: Well then they go back, which should be fine. You can override slash mess with what happens when a user clicks on the back button, but it's best not to.